# What is the web-searchable database of linguistic features?

Tags: cross-linguistic, reference-request

Years ago, I heard of a website that allowed you to search thousands of described languages by feature, like consonant inventory and word order.

It was an acronym, and I think it had multiple W's in it. What website am I thinking of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the [World Atlas of Language Structures](http://wals.info/) a.k.a. WALS.

Comment: you scooped me by 34 seconds :-)

Comment: 34 seconds and a word...

Comment: Finally. Thank you. For some reason it's terribly hard to find with Google.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about the [World Atlas of Linguistic Structures](http://www.wals.info)?